# Chrome extension auto updating selective script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Good day everyone. I'd like to ask a really quick question.

We'v heard about chrome's auto update feature for extensions.
but will this replace the old chrome extension fully as a whole or is it possible to partially update/overwrite only what's needed to be replaced.

Let's say I have the following files in my chrome extension.

ScriptA
ScriptB

and in my crx hosted online,
it contains only ScriptB

is it possble to overwrite ScriptB only?

or lets say ScriptA is a Json file and it contains settings.
is it possible to exclude it in the update and not get it changed or reset on update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome downloads the extension as a zip file, which essentially means that it replaces the entire crx file when you (the developer) update your extension.

If you want to have fine grained control of you assets you will need to host them outside the extension/app and store them in the HTML5Filesystem that is associated with your extension.

Comment: Thanks.. Hosting it was the answer :D